# Python - Django The submit button does not work when I submit a form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'am developing a website in Python Django.
I want to code a form which send me by email the email address that the users put in the form.
The problem is that the submit button does not work.
When I click the button submit, I am not redirected to a new page and I am not receiving the content of the form.
Can you help me to fix it ?

My views

```
def test(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = newsletterForm()
    else:
        form = newsletterForm(request.POST)
        if  form.is_valid():
            subject = 'New Subscriber'
            from_email = 'no-reply@test.com'
            message =  ' Email Adress: ' + form.cleaned_data['from_email']

            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['info@test.com'])
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you for contact us we will get back soon')
                render(request, "Test.html")

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            render(request, "Test.html")

    return render(request, "Test.html", {'form': form})
```

My HTML

```
<form id="newsletterForm" class="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="input-group input-group-rounded">
         {{ form.from_email|add_class:"form-control" }}
        <span class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-light text-color-dark" type="submit"><strong>GO!</strong></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

My forms

```
class newsletterForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(label='search',
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address'}))
```

Settings

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@test.com'  
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘xxx’
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'default from email'
```

Comment: You are not even redirecting the user anywhere in the view, why do you expect to be redirected?

Comment: It did not help because  the content of the form is not send to my email address and even if I change # by something else I am not redirected to another page.

Comment: Show your settings for the email (Redact sensitive values like the password, etc.) What have you set `EMAIL_HOST_USER` to? `no-reply@test.com`?

Comment: I added the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the form action to view url e.g.

```
 <form id="newsletterForm" class="contact-form" action="{%url ‘view_name’%}" method="post">
```